# Creating a column in the dataframe when comparing several dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes:

```
          df1                  df2                    df3
   scale   year   week         n_u         Code   H_k   year   week    n_u
0   -23    2016    20          131        002.55   1    2016    20     132
1   -22    2016    21          132        002.55   1    2016    23     132
2   -21    2016    22          ...        002.44   2    2016    22     131
                                          002.32   1    2016    20     131
                                          002.55   1    2016    22     131
                                          002.55   1    2016    24     132
                                          002.55   1    2016    21     132
                                          002.55   1    2016    21     131
                                          002.55   1    2016    24     131
                                          002.55   2    2016    21     131
                                          002.55   3    2016    22     132
                                          002.55   1    2016    22     132
...                                         ...
```

Also I have one variable `c1 = 002.55`. Every time I set the value of this variable.

I need to do the following:

Select all rows in the df3 if the values in the column "Code" are equal to the c1.

Then find all the values from the column n_u from the df2 (values in this column can be different). And for each unique value I need to create a column in the df1.

And count sum of values in the df3 in the column H_k for each row from the df1. I need to compare by years and weeks in the dataframes df1 and df3 (years and weeks can be different).

The result should look like this:

```
                  df1                 
   scale   year   week   131   132
0   -23    2016    20     1     1
1   -22    2016    21     3     1
2   -21    2016    22     1     4      
...
```

I hope the example will give a better understanding.

And all this is done before the value in the column "scale" is not equal to zero.

I thought I could use lambda. But I do not know how to write such a condition.

UPD I'll try to better describe the algorithm:

Select all rows in the `df3` where `df3['Code'] = c1`

While `scale` != 0:

for each unique value in `df2['n_u']` create new column in `df1` (is it generally possible to implement?)

`df1['each unique value from df2'] = sum values from df3['H_k'] on condition
df1['year'] = df3['year']
df1['week'] = df3['week']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html), then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate `sum` with reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html).

Last filter `df1` by `scale` and `df` [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to `df1`:

```
c1 = '002.55'
df = df3[(df3['Code'] == c1) & (df3['n_u'].isin(df2['n_u']))]
df = df.groupby(['year','week', 'n_u'])['H_k'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df)
n_u        131  132
year week          
2016 20      0    1
     21      3    1
     22      1    4
     23      0    1
     24      1    1

df = df1[df1['scale'] < 0].join(df, on=['year','week'])
print (df)
   scale  year  week  131  132
0    -23  2016    20    0    1
1    -22  2016    21    3    1
2    -21  2016    22    1    4
```